Issue with Deploying iOS App and Share Extension in .NET MAUI Using Visual Studio Code
I am working on implementing an iOS share extension for my .NET MAUI app, following the documentation provided here. I am using Visual Studio Code and have set up two projects: AppContainer and AppContainerShareExtension.
However, when I run mainProject, it deploys AppContainerShareExtension to the iOS emulator instead. Could you please advise if there is a configuration setting I might have overlooked in Visual Studio Code that could be causing this issue?
ScreenRecording of my problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oqu0-Sze15aTIgY0-OjFhLCBcN_KjRkw/view?usp=sharing.
Thank you.

You can check this issue thread about iOS Extensions. There is a solution here you can try it.

The issue was resolved by using the .NET Meteor debugger instead of the .NET MAUI debugger. There are likely some configuration settings that need to be adjusted in the .NET MAUI debugger. Those facing this issue can use the .NET Meteor debugger as a workaround.
